# How can I install Kali tools in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, software-sources, kali-linux-tools

I was reading a tutorial about installing Kali tools in Ubuntu. at the start, the instructions say to add repositories like this:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux2/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux2/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION main 
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION main
```

And in your Ubuntu version you have the following option

```
Ubuntu 12.04: Precise
Ubuntu 12.10: Quantal
Ubuntu 13.04: Raring
```

What is the code for 14.04? Can we install Kali tools in Ubuntu 14.04 or not?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty

Comment: @edwardtorvalds I rolled back your edit since it didn't remove the redundant line at the end.

Comment: @zeitue so can i install kali tools by using this?

Comment: @AnuragKumar no I thought you needed to know what the release name was. I looked and there are no packages for Trusty

Answer (score 0):

None of these PPAs support 13.10 or higher versions of Ubuntu. You can try using the code for 13.04 (`raring`), or install 12.04 and then use the PPA.

To get the code for any version of Ubuntu, use `lsb_release`:

```
$ lsb_release -sc
trusty
```

Comment: Quite a few tools are in the ubuntu repos and can be installed manually - eg `aircrack-ng`,`nmap`...

Comment: @KasiyA since these are PPAs: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:...` makes the `lsb_release` unnecessary.

Comment: @RohithMadhavan If you can make a comparative list, I think OP might find that as a useful answer.